# Inser output from ng-repeat in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a template in which I repeat trailer objects in my $scope.trailers, and add a angular directive that creates a embeded youtube players into the template,

```
.container-info
  .trailers
  %ul.trailers
    %li{"ng-repeat" => "trailer in trailers | filter: { movie_id: movie.movie_id}"}
      {{ trailer.link }}

  .container-trailers
    %youtube{:videoid => "M7lc1UVf-VE"}
```

As you can see now I have set a value of `M7lc1UVf-VE` as `videoid`. What I would like to do get the result of the first `{{ trailer.link }}` and insert it in the `videoid`.

The desired result would look like this,

```
<div class="container-info">
  <ul class="trailers">
    <li>ePbKGoIGAXY</li>
    <li>KlyknsTJk0w</li>
    <li>nyc6RJEEe0U</li>
    <li>zSWdZVtXT7E</li>
    <li>Lm8p5rlrSkY</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container-trailers">
    <youtube videoid="ePbKGoIGAXY"></youtube
  </div>
</div>
```

How could I achieve an result like this?

This is the youtube directive,

```
app.directive('youtube', function($window, youTubeApiService) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      videoid: "@"
    },
    template: '<div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, $rootScope) {
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;

      youTubeApiService.onReady(function() {
        player = setupPlayer(scope, element);
      });

      function setupPlayer(scope, element) {
        return new YT.Player(element.children()[0], {
          playerVars: {
            autoplay: 0,
            html5: 1,
            theme: "light",
            modesbranding: 0,
            color: "white",
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            showinfo: 1,
            controls: 1
          },
          videoId: scope.videoid,
        });
      }

      scope.$watch('videoid', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue == oldValue) {
          return;
        }
        player.cueVideoById(scope.videoid);

      });
      console.log ('youtube player directive')
    }
  };
});
```

It takes the `videoid` as a variable.

*** Additional but related question ***

Would it be possible to click on a `a` or other element to take the value of that element, and pass it to the `videoid` scope so the youtube videoid would be updated?

```
<div class="container-info">
  <ul class="trailers">
    <li><a href="#">ePbKGoIGAXY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">KlyknsTJk0w</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">nyc6RJEEe0U</a></li> <-- clicked element
    <li><a href="#">zSWdZVtXT7E</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lm8p5rlrSkY</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container-trailers">
    <youtube videoid="nyc6RJEEe0U"></youtube> <-- updated value of videoid
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While rendering `li` by filtering by `movie.movie_id` we will create a new array which will only have filtered value named as `filteredTrailers`. Then we will get first value from that filtered array by doing `filteredTrailers[0].link` will give you link of first object & this value will be passed to `videoid` attribute with `{{}}`(interpolation), because directive has property with `@`(one way binding).

**Markup**

```
.container-info
  .trailers
  %ul.trailers
    %li{"ng-repeat" => "trailer in filteredTrailers = (trailers | filter: { movie_id: movie.movie_id})"}
      {{ trailer.link }}

  .container-trailers
    %youtube{:videoid => "{{filteredTrailers[0].link}}"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Pankaj. Wauw, it works great. Although I'm not completly sure how. My main question is, what is `filteredTrailers`? It looks like a scope, if so, how is that scope accessible in the `container-trailer` below? What's their relationship?

Comment: Would it be possible to pass on other values as well? For example if I want to click on a li containing a `{{ trailer.link }}` and pass that value into the videoid so that a other trailer is being rendered.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma we have created `filteredTrailers` as temporary variable, which will be accessible throughout controller scope. and it gets evaluated on each digest cycle. if any change in `movie.movie_id` will reflect change in the corresponding `youtube` directive

Comment: Do you mean change in `videoid`?

Comment: The above comment i replied for 1st comment..i don't understand you second comment fully

Comment: Ah alright, that makes sense then. Very smart to do it that way. I didn't know angular could makes variables like that. For my second comment I've updated my question, maybe that would clear some things up.